# How to calculate a changing probability situation based on possible improvement? Can this problem not be solved precisely, just estimated?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A guy wants to win a stuffed animal bear for his girlfriend at a local carnival.  To get one requires winning a bean bag toss game where you try to toss it into a small hole. The guy goes to the local carnival a day early to practice solo.  He only practices $15$ tosses which is $3$ complete games of $5$ tosses each.  During the 1st, 2nd, and 3rd games he gets in $0$, $1$, and $2$ respectively.  He feels confident that he is improving so he stops.

The next day he goes to the carnival with his girlfriend and he must make any $3$ in out of $5$ in a single game to get the medium prize which is the bear she wants.  He feels that since he improved consistently during practice that he can make $3$ out of $5$.  He is nervous and misses the first shot but then makes the next $2$ shots so he only needs $1$ more out of $2$ shots to win the bear.

Question is what is the probability that he will actually make $3$ out of $5$ in this current unfinished game?  Do we base it on his lifetime of $5$ out of $18$ ($27.8$%) or do we somehow have to factor in that he has improved from $0$% the first game, to $20$% the 2nd game, to $40$% the 3rd game, to $66.7$% and still going in the 4th game? That is, should we account for the idea that he may be improving based on skill/practice and consider that in our model?  If so, what is the probability he will make $1$ of the last $2$ shots to win the bear and how do we compute that?  Assume that if he makes the 4th shot he will intentionally miss the 5th shot so he is assured of getting the bear and not a bigger prize.

Is there an exact answer to this question or would it be just an estimate?  For example, could we average his lifetime % of $27.8$% with his current "streak" of $66.7$% and come up with $47.25$% he will make shot # $4$?  If we do that, we didn't fully consider his consistent improvement during practice.

Many probability questions have fixed % outcomes such as a card draw or a coin toss but this one has changing probability so it is different.  I am curious how mathematics can handle a problem like this.

Comment: Too much text. Can you be more precise?

Comment: More precise about what?  I am asking what is the probability he will make 1 of the last 2 shots based on the history I gave in the body of the question.

Comment: this question can't really be answered rigorously without making additional assumptions

Comment: @mm-aops:  Well go ahead and make the assumptions but just state what they are in your answer(s).

Comment: Assuming each toss is independent of each other (which may not be true since if misses maybe he is more likely to miss on next shot) and each toss has same probabiltiy to be made (identically distrbuted bernoulli trials essentially) law of large numbers would say that 5/18 would be good estimate.

Comment: The thing is each toss is NOT independent of each other because he is improving.  Imagine something fairly easy but that you never did before.  You might do awful the first few tries but will likely quickly get better.  This problem is similar.  So how does Math handle this type of changing probability situation?  I suspect it has to be approximated and that there is not hard and fast rule(s) for it.  Is my answer to my own question reasonable or is there some better way to predict the outcome of this scenario?

Comment: Changing probabilities isnt managed as a beta distribution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the problem as stated needs additional assumptions to have a clear-cut solution. Make sure you understand why, as it's quite key to understanding how to properly model a real-life problem with probability theory.

My personal take would be to see this as a latent variable / Hidden Markov Model (HMM) situation. General intro on HMM here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model.

You could introduce a variable $Y_n$ corresponding to the $n$-th shot's outcome, and a hidden variable (or latent state) $X_n$ corresponding to the player's skill at time $n$. Assuming the player's success at time $n$ only depends on $X_n$ and not on $Y_{< n}$ (e.g. our guy does not stress out if he missed...), and $X_n$ only depends on $X_{n-1}$, our situation is perfectly described by the HMM below (illustration source [here](http://iacs-courses.seas.harvard.edu/courses/am207/blog/lecture-18.html)) : [image: figure 1]

Now you still need to make a handful of modeling assumptions, namely :

- a value range for $X_n$ (for instance $\{u^1, u^2, u^3\}$ = $\{$bad, average, good$\}$)
- a transition probability function : $P(X_n | X_{n-1})$ (for instance $P(u^i | u^i) = \alpha = 2/3$ and $P(u^{i+1} | u^i) = 1-\alpha$ if we assume the player can only get better with time)
- an output probability function : $P(Y_n | X_n)$ (i.e. in above's notations $P(\text{success} | u^i)$ for all $i$'s).

Once you've done all this, your problem is one of *inference*, namely calculating $P(Y_n | y_1, ..., y_{n-1})$ (where we use the common convention: $Y$ is the random variable and $y$ is a realisation of $Y$). The method for resolving this is way beyond this site's scope of course ...

**PS** : That's just a very simple approach of HMM described in layman's terms. The roughest assumption made here is guessing/fixing the model's parameters once and for all. The bayesian way would be to leave all parameters (i.e. the $a_{m,k} = P(X_n = u^m | X_{n-1} = u^k)$ and $b_k = P(Y_n = \text{success} | X_n = u^k)$) open and then to calculate $P(Y_n | y_1, ..., y_{n-1})$ by averaging over the model's parameter space (given $y_1, ..., y_{n-1})$). This paper http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/papers/ijprai.pdf mentions this technique, look for the words "*predictive distribution*".

**PPS** : Another approach could be to see the situation as a mixture model (MM) problem. *Wikipedia* link : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model. It's far less appropriate than HMMs but you may find it easier to understand.

In a nutshell, the typical MM example is one of a bag of $K$ indistinguishable coins which are of two types, each type in an unknown proportion $a_1 K$ and $a_2 K$ and having a given unknown flip bias, say $b_1$ and $b_2$. You start to pick one coin at random, and you flip it $m$ times. Then you put the coin back in the bag and you start again, $n$ times. The goal is to determine best estimates of $\theta = (a_1, a_2 = 1-a_1, b_1, b_2)$ from the outcome of the experiment. Then, with your parameters estimated, it's easy to evaluate the distribution of your next marginal draw. The common technique to estimate $\theta$ is called *Expectation maximization* (EM) and is described quickly in the wikipedia link above. Intuitively, if you see in your data that in 20% (resp. 80%) of the draws, the proportion of faces is between 10% and 30% with an average of 22% (resp. between 55% and 70% with an average of 63%), you're tempted to conclude that $a_1 = 20\%$, $a_2 = 80\%$, $b_1 = 22\%$ and $b_2 = 63\%$. Also, if a draw has a majority of faces, it's highly probable that the coin in that draw was of type 2. EM formalizes that and does a bit more...

Now, you could say that in your problem the player is, for each game $n$, either Type 1 (good) or Type 2 (bad) (MM works with more than 2 categories but let's keep it at two), with the probability $p$ of him being good unknown to you, and that in each state his probability of success is $b_1$ and $b_2$. Run EM (or any other method), it will give you best estimates for $p$ and $b_i$. It will also give you, for each game $n$, the probability that the player was good in this particular game, say $q_n$. *Here comes the fiddling* : then plot $n \mapsto q_n$, hopefully it should be roughly increasing and come up with an extrapolation/approximation that will give you a *guess* (let's not call it an estimate) for $q_{n+1}$. A best guess for your probability of success in the future game $n+1$ is now $P(\text{success}_{n+1}) = q_{n+1} \hat b_1 + (1-q_{n+1}) \hat b_2$. Heck, it's really dirty, as some assumptions here are self-contradictory, but it's a start and my old physics teacher would have been satisfied with it.

Comment: Have you read the answer and the links ? You can also check this one <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_variable> about latent variables in general to see how/why your concept of "player's skill" can/should be modeled with a latent variable. Not knowing *ex ante* what your math level is, it was hard to provide the answer you expected. But any *proper* answer would have to be undergrad level imho.

Comment: My profile states I am not a math major but I am college educated in Computer Science so I only have very basic math skills but I can do simple probability problems.  I like to try to keep math solutions as simple as possible.  I don't yet see how any modelling solution can "beat" my simple solution because my weighted solution accounts for his improving ability.  I guess I could have added more info such as an "elite" level bean bag tosser (such as the attendant) "maxes" out at about 75% make rate so we can assume the guy trying to win the bear will never do better than that.

Comment: Let's not fight over who should have done what. You asked what "the field of mathematics" (so mathematicians ?) has to say about your problem, I made an attempt at answering that in simple terms, try to see through it. Worst case you will get a sense that probability theory is hard...

Answer (score 0):

If I had to answer this question myself, I would say that I see a pattern of consistent improvement so I would assign "weights" to each game.  For example, his first game he got $0$ in so that would be assigned a weight of $0.1$.  His 2nd game he got $1$ in and that has a weight of $0.2$.  His 3rd game he got $2$ in so that has a weight of $0.3$.  His 4th partial game he got $2$ of $3$ in so that has a weight of $0.4$.  The higher valued weights mean that run is more significant because it is more recent and better reflects his improvement and current skill level.

So here is the math.

Game $1$:    $\ \   0$%    weighted $0.1$.
Game $2$:   $20$% weighted $0.2$.
Game $3$:   $40$% weighted $0.3$.
Game $4$: $66.7$% weighted $0.4$.

Adding up the weighted percentages we get $0$% + $4$% + $12$% + $26.67$% = $42.67$%.

One thing to consider is game $4$ has not been completed so it is debatable whether it should have a $0.4$ weighting or not.

I don't know how accurate this is but it seems reasonable. This would be the estimated probability he will make the 4th shot, however, it doesn't answer the original question fully.  For example, he may miss the 4th shot and not yet win the game.  Then we would have to compute the probability of him making the 5th shot.   If he makes the 4th shot or the 5th shot he will win so that is the probability I am looking for.

So let's try to get a final probability.  If he misses the 4th shot, he must then make the 5th shot to get the intended prize.  Well at that point he will be $2$ out of $4$ in game $4$ and the pressure is on cuz it is a "must make" shot.  We have no data for "pressure" shots so I would have to say his chance of making the final (5th) shot is maybe $1$ in $3$.  So then the chances of him missing both the 4th and 5ths shots would be ($1 - 42.67$%) * ($1 - 33.33$%) = $38.22$% which means there is a $61.78$% chance he will win the bear prize.

Comment: Is there any theoretical tool you're thinking of when doing your weighted average sums?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by theoretical tool.  To me it seems that his more recent shots are more significant than "old" shots but they all count since they are all part of his history for the game.  The purpose of this type of word problem is to get a general idea how to model a situation where the probability is changing (the person is getting better at the game).  This is unlike random die tosses and random card draws where the probability is "constant".

Comment: My point was just to draw your attention on the fact that probability theory is quite a demanding (easily misleading) tool and you should in general stick to implementing tools/lines of reasoning found in classes and books. See my proposed answer for an example of theoretical framework. Note that your answer is equivalent to assuming that Game $i$ was repeated $i$ times and all *pseudo-games* are i i d.

Comment: I took the "simple mans" approach to coming up with a model to predict his more recent shot probabilities based on his improving history.  I don't remember ever seeing a problem like this in my college discrete math class so I was curious about it.  So many probability word problems I see make the assumption that the probability of some trial such as making a basketball free throw shot stays constant during some event such as shooting 10 free throw shots but in reality, the shooter could be improving in that time, thus changing his individual trial probability. This question addresses that.

Comment: I doubt any serious solution would be sub-undergraduate level, but let's see what other people come up with

Comment: I think my weighted solution is not bad and is simple to understand. I don't think there is any exact answer to this question since we don't know if the person is improving at a steady repeatable rate and we don't know what other factors are involved such as the "choke" factor when he only needs $1$ more make to win the prize. However, I suspect my extremely simple model is a reasonable approximation to the real probability of him making the next shot. So to calculate if he will make $1$ of his last $2$ shots in game $4$, it should be a straightforward calculation.

Comment: You probably just accessed the site from a non-logged-in browser session